# Default initialization in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

Default initialization in C++11?

I am not sure which style should I use:

```
T o;
T o{};
```

Is there difference?

Comment: I think `T o;` is most common.  Also, do you mean `T o();`?

Comment: @thesquaregroot, no he doesn't. That's C++11's new initialization syntax. using parentheses results in the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Comment: I think there are a good minor points here. `T o{};` won't work on old compilers, and it may scare some people who are out of touch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`T o;` performs [default initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) (in particular, it leaves non-class members uninitialized)

`T o{};` performs [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) (in particular, it zeroes out non-class members)

Comment: What do you mean by non-class members?

Comment: @user3111311 members of non-class types (ints, pointers, arrays of such, etc)

Comment: Can you also please edit your post to add comment about, if we should always prefer {} initialization because it won't leave any members uninitialized?

Comment: @AndyProwl I think you are correct, I was about to ask this also.

Comment: remember {} isnt strictly better, the first is potentially faster than the second. and there is little point in setting things to zero if we are about to squash them in the next few lines.

Comment: Note that whether the value initialization zeros out built-ins and PODs can depend on whether `T` has a user defined default constructor or whether any of the members are initialized at the point of declaration.

Comment: @user3111311: You shouldn't "always prefer" anything, ever. Stop looking for mantras to follow: where you find them, they shall serve you poorly.